# Google Map Kitkat(API 19) Its work fine but in Marshmallow(API 23) it crashing Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am learning android google map.I already designed app, its working fine in kitkat but when i want to run same app in marshmallow it crashes. I trying to solve it but i am not getting any result to solve this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
String location;
GoogleApiClient apiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (googleServicesAvailable()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Perfect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initMap();
    } else {
        //No Google Map Layout
    }

}

// Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
private void initMap() {
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

public boolean googleServicesAvailable() {
    GoogleApiAvailability api = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int isAvailable = api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return true;
    } else if (api.isUserResolvableError(isAvailable)) {
        Dialog dialog = api.getErrorDialog(this, isAvailable, 0);
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cant connect to play services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    // goToLocationZoom(12.9090502,77.6241984,10);
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    //  LatLng ll = new LatLng(12.912128, 77.623557);

    // CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ll);
    //mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
    // mMap.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo( 17.0f ) );

    //  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    // mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));


    apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    apiClient.connect();

}

public void goToLocation(double lat, double lng) {
    LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ll);
    mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
}

public void goToLocationZoom(double lat, double lng, float zoom) {
    LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
    mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);

}

 Marker marker;

public void geolocation(View view) throws IOException {
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    location = editText.getText().toString();

    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
    Address address = list.get(0);
    String locality = address.getLocality();

    Toast.makeText(this, locality, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    double lat = address.getLatitude();
    double lng = address.getLongitude();

    goToLocationZoom(lat, lng, 20);

    setMarker(locality, lat, lng);

}

private void setMarker(String locality, double lat, double lng) {
    if(marker!=null){
        marker.remove();
    }

    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .title(locality)
           // .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW))
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_car))
            .position(new LatLng(lat,lng))
            .snippet("I am here");

    marker = mMap.addMarker(options);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_none) {
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_normal) {
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_terrain) {
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_satellite) {
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_hybrid) {
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);



    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(apiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(location == null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cant get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }else{
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll,15);
        mMap.animateCamera(update);
    }

}
```

}

here my XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"

    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/geolocation"
    android:text="click"
    android:onClick="geolocation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp" />


<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="360dp"
    tools:context="ab.googlemaplinear.MainActivity" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Here My menifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<!-- EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions are optional for Android 6.0 onwards. -->


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>
</application>
```

Logcat

```
07-15 16:46:00.922 21241-21241/abinfosoft.googlemaplinear E/AndroidRuntime: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: abinfosoft.googlemaplinear, PID: 21241
                                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5265)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21534)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5265) 
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21534) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
                                                                         Caused by: java.io.IOException: Service not Available
                                                                            at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocationName(Geocoder.java:178)
                                                                            at abinfosoft.googlemaplinear.MainActivity.geolocation(MainActivity.java:132)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5265) 
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21534) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

07-15 16:46:01.180 13453-16118/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: , App: com.google.android.gms, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contextcontroller
                                         edw: Long live credential not available.
                                             at edx.b(:com.google.android.gms:0)
                                             at edx.a(:com.google.android.gms:17)
                                             at eck.a(:com.google.android.gms:51)
                                             at fig.a(:com.google.android.gms:7)
                                             at fig.a(:com.google.android.gms:3)
                                             at fhh.a(:com.google.android.gms:1)
                                             at fhf.a(:com.google.android.gms:17)
                                             at fhf.a(:com.google.android.gms:5)
                                             at bvd.a(:com.google.android.gms:192)
                                             at bvd.a(:com.google.android.gms:67)
                                             at dzh.a(:com.google.android.gms:5)
                                             at dzg.a(:com.google.android.gms:1)
                                             at dzg.e(:com.google.android.gms:5)
                                             at dzg.d(:com.google.android.gms:0)
                                             at dze.b(:com.google.android.gms:0)
                                             at lbv.a(:com.google.android.gms:0)
                                             at lam.a(:com.google.android.gms:2)
                                             at clb.a(:com.google.android.gms:58)
                                             at cgf.run(:com.google.android.gms:1)
                                             at cgd.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms:2)
                                             at lgr.run(:com.google.android.gms:5)
                                             at lhb.run(:com.google.android.gms:24)
                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                             at lmc.run(:com.google.android.gms:0)
                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-15 16:46:01.217 13453-16118/? E/ctxmgr: [BaseServerTask]Server task (FetchAclSet) got error statusCode=-1.
                                           com.android.volley.VolleyError: Unable to obtain auth token - is the device online?
                                               at clb.a(:com.google.android.gms:66)
                                               at cgf.run(:com.google.android.gms:1)
                                               at cgd.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms:2)
                                               at lgr.run(:com.google.android.gms:5)
                                               at lhb.run(:com.google.android.gms:24)
                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                               at lmc.run(:com.google.android.gms:0)

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: `I trying to solve it` ... what are you doing to solve it?  I would add breakpoints in every maps method and find out quickly where it is dying.  It could be a versioning/deprecation error, or something else.

Comment: wait i am updating my menifest @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @Abhishek Kumar Post your log cat with exception.

Comment: okay @AndyDeveloper

Comment: Well try to update the google play service in your device. Which google play service version you are using in your gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

have you try runtime permission for access location ?